# Why Superfluid Vacuum Theory has not proved yet that Vacuum space is possible a superfluid?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, cosmology, vacuum, superconductivity, superfluidity

Our Universe and subatomic world being defects of an omnipresent type of superfluid we call "Vacuum Space" therefore a medium, unknown phase of matter is an intriguing idea expressed by [SVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfluid_vacuum_theory).

So the question why this theory cannot prove this hypothesis yet?

If it is a superfluid it cannot be so radically different from the known superfluids of He-4 and He-3 we are constructing in the lab. It should generate [quantized vortices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_vortex) when rotated (i.e. our Universe rotates) which in a sense would be the subatomic mass particles thus similar to discrete energy vortices and also Black holes could be expressed as vortices in this superfluid and there are also other characteristics about superfluids we are familiar with like frictionless etc.

So, why we cannot  conceive an experiment that could conclusively prove this theory. Why we cannot detect in the lab this Vacuum space superfluid and it is so elusive? Could it have additional characteristic like superluminous propagation of energy or negative mass?

I had like to hear it from experts from this research field of what the difficulties are in proving this theory.

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/123539/226902 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/694669/226902 , book for reference: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/526845/226902

Answer (score -1):

Please read my book S. Küchler: "Von den kleinsten Dingen - Gravitation und starke Wechselwirkung" (wich is available at Diligentia-Verlag - https://www.diligentia-verlag.de/ ).

In this book, it is disclosed that a verification of the existence of a superfluid vacuum can only be made by indirect indicators.

Mathematical calculations leed to the fact that a superfluid vacuum would necessarily imply the existence of effects like gravity force and strong nuclear force.

S. Küchler

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/421163)